# How to reload Self-defined plugin in Cordova/Ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to build an application, and have built a plugin to linkup the html-side and java-side.

However, every time I make changes to the plugin, I need to `ionic platform rm android`, than `ionic platform add android`, hence to refresh the plugin in corresponding android project.

Is there any command or method to help me quickly to achieve such purpose?

Comment: you can remove the plugin and reinstall it.

Comment: I defined by my self, by creating a folder in /plugin, ...such a handwork

Comment: so that I don't know how to install it by ``cordova plugin add xxxxxxxx``, (no repo)

Comment: just give the local file name .. or make a local server and give that url.. like xampp, or chrome simple http server.

Comment: how to direct the ionic to fetch the source from local?

Comment: it gives me ``Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/my-customized-plugin``

Comment: Done,  well I just put the source at ``D:\plugin\my-customize-plugin``, and run ``cordova plugin add D:\plugin\my-customize-plugin``,  and everything working

Comment: And if you run `ionic plugin add D:\plugin\my-customize-plugin --save` the plugin will be added to the config.xml. Then you will only have to remove the plugin (without --save flag) and it will be automatically reinstalled on your next `ionic run`.

Comment: thx a lot, it's a good solution!